# VisualForce: Conditionally render HTML elements like <li>

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, html

I have a Force.com site portal written completely with custom Visualforce, HTML and CSS.

I have a component which is used to display the navigation links at the top of the page.
This navigation is built using  and

tags which is pretty common.

```
<ul id="hdrnav">
                <li><a href="/apex/billing" id="billnav">Billing</a></li>
                <li><a href="/apex/deposits" id="depositsnav">Deposits</a></li>  
                <li><a href="/apex/checks" id="checksnav">Checks</a></li>   

            </ul>
```

Now I want to be able to render these

links based on the user's security as each of these links display information from different custom objects.

I know we can check a user's access to a record using something like:

```
{!$ObjectType.objectname.accessible}
```

So how can I achieve something like not displaying the

link for deposits if the user has no access to the deposit custom object.

Comment: Are you on Force.com Sites or Site.com?

Comment: Force.com sites. Editing.

Comment: Just bind in output pannel .Should be good what Josh suggesting

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Off the cuff, I believe you can overload the use of the `<apex:variable>` tag along with its rendered attribute to show/hide individual elements.

```
<apex:variable var="foo" rendered="{!$ObjectType.objectname.accessible} >
    <li> bar ... </li>
</apex:variable>
```

Comment: This worked for me, however I had to add the value='foo' attribute.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit off the cuff, but I think you can wrap it in a panel:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$ObjectType.objectname.accessible}" layout="none"><!-- content --> </apex:outputPanel>
```

Would that work in your case?

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to compose them server side, then display with `<apex:dataList>` or `<apex:repeat>`. Useful especially if the list will grow in future?

To do that build some wrapper apex class  (or even something as simple as `Map<String, String>`) that would hold the URL and display name. Anything you can do in VF with `{!$ObjectType.Account.accessible}` you can check with [`Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm)

Comment: This answer gets my vote as it keeps the business logic in the  controller where it belongs, while the page simply iterates the collection it is given and renders it.

Comment: @BobBuzzard Thx :) I'm torn about that one to be honest. Sometimes I do a lot of magic in `rendered` if it's just for display related, not manipulating the data. Plus I think describes used on the page don't count towards the governor limit?

Comment: Thanks for letting me how I can do this in the controller as well. The answers here will help folks no doubt. For my specific purposes and for its simplicity to implement, I will go with Kevin's solution. Another thing is I know VF will render <Apex:DataList> as <ul> and <li>. I wish Salesforce gives us new apex equivalents of <ul> and <li>. I have some formatting CSS on these elements as well. Thank you. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

If the VF level or Controller level is not an option (the two first things I would try) - then you could also potentially control it via jQuery.  Give the LI's you want to hide a specific class, and then tie it back to a function which checks if the user *has* the permission, and then *shows* the LI (instead of the other way around).