# How to build Relationship between Territory object and Custom objects?

Tags: territory-management

Is there a way to have a relationship established between Territory object and custom objects. It can be either via look-up relation or master-detail relation.

And can we change the name of the filed (**Territories**) which is displayed on Account's detail page to any other custom label such as Zones/Regions, etc.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe custom objects fall under the scope of Territory Management, it is primarily focused on Accounts.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_def.htm&language=en_US

If your custom objects can fall under accounts, I think you can give them a Master-Detail relationship with the accounts and inherit the security access. Otherwise, you'll be stuck with **Sharing Rules**.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&language=en_US

With regards to changing the name of the field, if it is available it would likely be under **Renaming Tabs & Labels**.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_rename.htm&language=en_US

Comment: +1. If you'll enable PersonAccounts you can manage them via territories too (not that I recommend the whole business, I got my share of a$$ bitten: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10649/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-territory-management). And then there's always apex-managed sharing ;)

Comment: Hi @Michael, regarding renaming of a field in "Accounts - Detail page", I couldn't find that particular name in the "Renaming Tabs and Labels" for Account object.